# ¿Cómo hacer la siguiente consulta SQL?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

En mi BD, tengo tablas con la columna `IdEmpresa` en común.
La siguiente consulta, me muestra todas las tablas que tienen la columna `IdEmpresa`:

```
Select TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE COLUM_NAME LIKE '%IdEmpresa%' 

tabla1
tabla2
tabla3
tabla4
tabla5
```

Sin embargo, necesito saber cuál de ellas tienen el valor `P_208` en la columna `IdEmpresa`.

¿Alguien sabe cómo realizar una consulta sobre otra?

Comment: Que motor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Estoy usando SQL SERVER

Answer (score 4):

No te queda otra, que construir una sentencia dinámica para luego hacer una consulta en cada tabla mediante un `sp_executesql`. Conceptualmente algo así:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @SQL = 'WITH CTE AS (' + CHAR(13)
SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + 'SELECT ''' + TABLE_NAME + ''' AS TABLE_NAME,  COUNT(1) AS Cant FROM ' +  
        TABLE_NAME + ' WHERE ' + COLUMN_NAME + ' = ''P_208'' UNION' + CHAR(13)
        FROM information_schema.columns WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%IdEmpresa%' 
SELECT  @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL)-6) + ')' + CHAR(13) + 
        'SELECT TABLE_NAME, CANT FROM CTE WHERE CANT > 1'

-- Imprimimos la sentencia dinámica     
PRINT @SQL

-- Ejecutamos la sentencia
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Comment: Yo creo que está usando PostgreSQL. Si es así, no hay manera de hacer esto en una sentencia SQL. Debería hacerlo en una stored procedured.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer lo que pides, necesitas recurrir al código dinámico. Este es un tema complejo porque pueden pasar muchas cosas si no se realiza de manera correcta. Necesitamos crear una instrucción que inserte datos en una tabla si existe el dato que buscas. Para validar la existencia de un dato, no queremos contar todo, por lo tanto usaremos la función EXISTS().

```
--ELIMINAR TABLA TEMPORAL SI EXISTE
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TablaTemporal', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TablaTemporal;

--TABLA TEMPORAL
CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal (NombreTabla varchar(50));

--DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000);

--DECLARACIÓN DEL CURSOR
DECLARE Instrucciones CURSOR 

FOR 
SELECT REPLACE( 'INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal 
    SELECT ''<<nombre_tabla>>'' 
    WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * FROM <<nombre_tabla>> WHERE IdEmpresa = ''P_208''); ' , '<<nombre_tabla>>', QUOTENAME( TABLE_NAME))
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%IdEmpresa%';

--APERTURA DEL CURSOR
OPEN Instrucciones;

--LECTURA DE LA PRIMERA FILA DEL CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM Instrucciones INTO @SQL;

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    --Para validar el código generado
    PRINT @SQL;

    --Ejecutar el código dinámico
    EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SQL;

    --LECTURA DE LA SIGUIENTE FILA DE UN CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM Instrucciones INTO @SQL;
END

--CIERRA EL CURSOR
CLOSE Instrucciones;

--LIBERAR RECURSOS DEL CURSOR
DEALLOCATE Instrucciones;

--MOSTRAR NOMBRE DE TABLAS DE LA BD, CUYO VALOR DEL CAMPO DE LA COLUMNA "IdEmpresa" SEA "P_208".
SELECT * FROM #TablaTemporal;
```

Answer (score -3):

Esto puedes lograrlo utilizando cursores.

Antes, crea una tabla temporal en la cual registrarás los nombres de las tablas cuyo condición sea true.

A continuación, se explica línea a línea cada sección de la sentencia sql.

## Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
/*ELIMINAR TABLA TEMPORAL SI EXISTE*/
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TablaTemporal', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TablaTemporal;

/*TABLA TEMPORAL*/
CREATE TABLE #TablaTemporal (NombreTabla varchar(50))

/*DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES*/
DECLARE @FLAG_EXISTE AS INT
DECLARE @TABLE_NAME AS nvarchar(400)
SET @FLAG_EXISTE = 0

/*DECLARACIÓN DEL CURSOR*/
DECLARE name_cursor CURSOR 

FOR 
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  COLUM_NAME LIKE '%IdEmpresa%' 

/*APERTURA DEL CURSOR*/
OPEN name_cursor

/*LECTURA DE LA PRIMERA FILA DEL CURSOR*/
FETCH NEXT FROM name_cursor INTO @TABLE_NAME

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    SET FLAG_EXISTE = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TABLE_NAME WHERE IdEmpresa = 'P_208')

    IF FLAG_EXISTE > 0
     BEGIN
        /*INSERTAR NOMBRE DE TABLAS DE LA BD EN TABLA TEMPORAL, CUYO VALOR DEL CAMPO DE LA COLUMNA "IdEmpresa" SEA "P_208".*/
        INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal(NombreTabla) VALUES(@TABLE_NAME)
     END

    /*LECTURA DE LA SIGUIENTE FILA DE UN CURSOR*/
    FETCH NEXT FROM name_cursor INTO @TABLE_NAME
END

/*CIERRA EL CURSOR*/
CLOSE name_cursor

/*LIBERAR RECURSOS DEL CURSOR*/
DEALLOCATE name_cursor

/*MOSTRAR NOMBRE DE TABLAS DE LA BD, CUYO VALOR DEL CAMPO DE LA COLUMNA "IdEmpresa" SEA "P_208".*/
SELECT * FROM #TablaTemporal
```

**Nota:** cualquier duda o comentario, quedo atento.

Comment: Podrias explicar un poco tu respuesta? las respuestas que son solo codigo suelen ser mal recibidas

Comment: La respuesta es incorrecta, se necesita código dinámico, no solo usar una variable para el nombre de la tabla.

Comment: Lo entiendo, pero para una persona que desarrolla, me parece con todos los comentarios que puse en la sentencia sql, debería ser suficiente. Acabo de poner una breve descripción al inicio. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @LuisCazares, al utilizar el cursor, los valores que se guardan son de la consulta inicial que colocó el usuario: SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM   information_schema.columns 
WHERE  COLUM_NAME LIKE '%IdEmpresa%' . La sentencia sugerida si es dinámica. Slds.

Comment: No tienes ningún código dinámico ahí. Además, tu código genera 7 errores al ejecutarlo. Es importante probar las soluciones antes de publicarlas.

Comment: Es posible, lo hice en un archivo de texto plano, porque no cuento con sql instalado en mi pc. Ayudarías mucho si dieras la solución antes de  seguir criticando. Slds-